# How to make a post accessible from multiple post type slugs?

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

**I have two custom post types**

1. colors
2. shapes

**I have a post called "red" under the custom post type "colors"**. The default URL for this post would be

> example.com/colors/red

Now **I want to make it accessible from the following URL** as well

> example.com/shapes/red

The closest I came with is to add a filter to change_404_template (as I receive a 404 for above url) and forcefully inject the single.php file with some hacky code.

Is there a way more standard method to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the way, For anyone looking for a method in the future I'll mention how I made it work.

```
add_action( 'parse_request', function($query){  
    $post_type = $post_name = NULL;

    if (isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && in_array($query->query_vars['post_type'], ['colors', 'shapes'])) {
        $post_type = $query->query_vars['post_type'];
        $post_name = $query->query_vars['name'];
    } elseif (isset($query->query_vars['pagename']) &&  isset($query->request) && isset(explode('/', $query->request)[0]) && in_array(explode('/', $query->request)[0], ['slug-with-no-post-type', 'another-slug-with-no-post-type'])) {
        $division = explode('/', $query->request)[0];
        if (isset(explode('/', $query->request)[1])) $post_type = explode('/', $query->request)[1];
        unset($query->query_vars['pagename']);
    }

    if($post_type && $post_name){
        if ($post = get_page_by_path($post_name, 'OBJECT', ['colors', 'shapes'])) {
            if (isset($post->post_type) && $post->post_type != $post_type) {
                $query->query_vars['post_type'] = $post->post_type;
                $query->query_vars['post_type_template'] = $post_type;
                $query->query_vars['name'] = $post_name;
            }
        }
    }
});
```